# Find Data Rows in Text File

Tags: c#, file

I have a text file (it's actual an Intel Hex file but the data is ASCII text) and I haven't been able to come up with a way to find the starting and ending rows of zero data.

The file will start with rows of data and then could have a few rows that are zero and then data again. What I'm trying to do is to find the location of the last group of zeros.

As an example the file might contain this:

```
:1234567890
:0987654321
:0000000000
:0000000000
:ABCDEFABCD
:DCBAFEDCBA
:0000000000
:0000000000
:0000000000
:9999999999
```

For this file I would want to return row #7 as the starting row and row #9 as the ending row.

I'm currently using StreamReader and ReadLine like this:

```
StreamReader srHexFile = File.OpenText(m_pathHexFile);
while ((readData = srHexFile.ReadLine()) != null)
....
```

But I'm having a mental block on the best way to loop through and set/reset the starting and ending rows.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Based on suggestion from @user993533 I'm working with the following function but it's returning 2881 for firstZeroRow where it should be 2883.

Here's the new code:

```
 private int FindEndofFlashData()
    {
        int lineNumber = 0;
        String readData;
        String zeroRowData = "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        int firstZeroRow = -1; // Will hold the location that starts the zero data
        //int lastZeroRow = m_numberOfFlashRows - 2;  // We know where to stop looking from m_numberOfFlashRows
        int lastZeroRow = -1;
        bool groupEnded = true;
        StreamReader srHexFile = File.OpenText(m_pathHexFile);

        /* Loop till the main flash row data ends, which will be used to calculate the number of lines in hex file for
         * flash rows.  Each line of hex file will have data for 1/2 th of a Flash row (64 bytes)*/
        while (((readData = srHexFile.ReadLine()) != null) && (lineNumber < (m_numberOfFlashRows*4 - 4)))
        {

            if ((readData[HEX_FILE_RECORD_TYPE_CHAR_0_INDEX] == HEX_FILE_DATA_RECORD_CHAR_0) && (readData[HEX_FILE_RECORD_TYPE_CHAR_1_INDEX] == HEX_FILE_DATA_RECORD_CHAR_1))
            {
                lineNumber++;

                if (readData.Substring(9, 128) == zeroRowData)
                {
                    if(groupEnded)
                    {
                        firstZeroRow = lineNumber;
                        groupEnded = false;
                    }

                    lastZeroRow = lineNumber;
                }
                else
                {
                    groupEnded = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {

                if ((readData[HEX_FILE_RECORD_TYPE_CHAR_0_INDEX] == HEX_FILE_EXTEND_LINEAR_RECORD_CHAR_0) &&
                    (readData[HEX_FILE_RECORD_TYPE_CHAR_1_INDEX] == HEX_FILE_EXTEND_LINEAR_RECORD_CHAR_1))
                {
                    if (readData[HEX_FILE_EXTENDED_ADDR_CHAR_1_INDEX] >= HEX_FILE_EXTENDED_ADDR_NON_FLASH_REGION)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("First Zero Row is: {0}", firstZeroRow);
        Console.WriteLine("Last Zero Row is: {0}", lastZeroRow);
        return (firstZeroRow);
    }
```

Comment: well, looping you already have, whats your problem with next?

Answer (score 0):

```
    long firstZeroRow = -1;
    long lastZeroRow = -1;
    long rowNum = 0;

    StreamReader srHexFile = File.OpenText(m_pathHexFile);
    while ((readData = srHexFile.ReadLine()) != null){
       rowNum++;
       if (readData.equals(":0000000000" /*or ":0000000000\n"*/)){
           if (firstZeroRow == -1){
               firstZeroRow = rowNum;
           }
           lastZeroRow = rowNum;
       }
    }

    if (firstZeroRow == -1){
        System.out.println("firstZeroRow: " + firstZeroRow);
        System.out.println("lastZeroRow: " + lastZeroRow);
    }
```

Comment: seems very close but the first row of the last group is needed (#7). `rowNum` can be compared to `lastZeroRow` to check if the previous line was zero

Comment: yes, right, or to add a flag `groupEnded=true` and reset it every time value is not zero

     if (readData.equals(":0000000000")){
           if (groupEnded){
               firstZeroRow = rowNum;
               groupEnded = false;
           }
           lastZeroRow = rowNum;
       }
       else{ 
           groupEnded=true;
     }

Comment: thanks, this is right along the lines that I was trying to think through. I'm not a daily programmer (hardware guy by nature) so I was getting stuck on the logic to use to reset the flag. I'll give this a try later and let you know how it works.

Comment: user993533 I edited my original post to add in the new function based on your suggestion. The results are close, off by 2 rows, so I'm missing something. I'm heading out so I have to stop debugging but thought I'd post what I've done in hopes to keep this thread going.

Comment: I think, `lineNumber++` should be unconditional - next line after while (outside of `if` block)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not clear what the overall goal is… I used a different approach. Instead of trying to juggle the last starting and ending rows of zeros while reading in the data, I simply made a list of those rows that are all zeros. Then simply sort the list from high to low to get the row index of the last row with zeros. Then using the same list, to get the first/starting index of the last zero(s) group, starting from the top of the list, a check is made to see if the adjacent indexes are contiguous. If the indexes are contiguous then we simply keep going until the next element index is NOT contiguous at which point we would know where the last group started. If we get to the end of the list, then you would know that the list started with a row of zeros at which case the index would be 0. I am aware that my indexes are off by 1 from your post because I started with a zero (0) index and not 1.

```
private static void GetStartEndOfLastGroupOfZeros() {
  string readData = "";
  int rowNum = 0;
  List<int> rowsOfZero = new List<int>();
  StreamReader srHexFile = File.OpenText(m_pathHexFile);
  while ((readData = srHexFile.ReadLine()) != null) {
    if (readData.Equals(":0000000000")) {
      rowsOfZero.Add(rowNum);
    }
    rowNum++;
  }
  rowsOfZero.Reverse();
  PrintIndexes(rowsOfZero);
  if (rowsOfZero.Count < 1) {
    Console.WriteLine("There are NO rows that are :0000000000");
  }
  else {
    Console.WriteLine("\n\rStart line number of Last Zero Group: " + GetFirstIndexOfLastGroupOfZeroRows(rowsOfZero));
    Console.WriteLine("End line number of Last Zero Group: " + GetLastIndexOfLastGroupOfZeroRows(rowsOfZero));
  }
}

private static int GetFirstIndexOfLastGroupOfZeroRows(List<int> rowsOfZero) {
  if (rowsOfZero.Count < 1)  // <- if there are not any int in the list then there are no zero rows return -1;
    return -1;
  if (rowsOfZero.Count < 2)  // <- if there is only one row then it starts and ends on that single row
      return rowsOfZero[0];
  if (rowsOfZero[1] + 1 != rowsOfZero[0])  // <-- if the second element(1) is not contiguous, then the last row is a single zero row,
    return rowsOfZero[0];                  // <-- so the start line of the last group will be the same as the end line index 
  int startOfThisGroup = 0;
  for (int i = 2; i < rowsOfZero.Count; i++) {
    if (rowsOfZero[i] + 1 == rowsOfZero[i - 1]) {  // <-- if they are contiguous then we have a new startOfThisGroup row, if not we are done checking
      startOfThisGroup = rowsOfZero[i];
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return startOfThisGroup;
}

private static int GetLastIndexOfLastGroupOfZeroRows(List<int> rowsOfZero) {
  if (rowsOfZero.Count < 1)
    return 0;
  return rowsOfZero[0];
}

private static void PrintIndexes(List<int> rowsOfZero) {
  if (rowsOfZero.Count < 1) {
    Console.WriteLine("No zero rows");
  }
  else {
    Console.Write("Sorted (high to low) row indexes that are ':0000000000' -> ");
    foreach (int curInt in rowsOfZero)
      Console.Write(curInt + " ");
  }
  Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks for taking the time to think about this. To answer your question about the end goal I'm working on a project where I'll be programming some processors. When the firmware is compiled (PSoC) the resulting Intel Hex file has data for the entire flash area and uses a zero fill at the end of the code up to the end of the flash. There is some metadata at the end of the file which can vary so I need to find this range. I'm bit banging the programming of the processors so to save time I wanted to stop at the end of the actual data.

Comment: @George Ioakimedes. Thanks for letting us in on what your goal is. FYI I thoroughly tested this code and it works properly. Depending on the amount of data and the number of zero rows, I thought this would be an easier approach. Hope you get it working with your approach.